# For security purposes framing is not allowed in chrome

Tags: security, google-chrome, frame

I got this alert in Chrome (Ubuntu Version 31.0.1650.63)

> For security purposes framing is not allowed. Click ok to remove the frames

I get this alert 2-3 times for stackoverflow, metastackoverflow and any other stackexchange site I am opening.

After clicking on `Ok`, I no longer get this alert on reloading the page.

**What is present on the page which is triggering this alert and what is chrome doing behind the scenes ?**

Here is the screenshot as the proof

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but this is not happening to me anymore. Any guesses what could be the possible reasons?

Comment: May be something happened on stackexchange sites that day?